# How do I find xml tag and generate a sequentional number using perl?

Tags: xml, regex, perl

I have xml data like this

```
<ce:refers type="book">DHO</ce:refers>
<ce:refers type="journal" num="ref0005">RTO</ce:refers>
<ce:refers type="book">DHO</ce:refers>
<ce:refers type="journal">RHO</ce:refers>
<ce:refers type="book">DHO</ce:refers>
<ce:refers type="book" num="ref0010">EHO</ce:refers>
```

Now i want find tag which don't have num attribute and generate num value, the num value are increment by 5 and need to change num without affecting exiting num and no same num value are not allowed.

I tried with regex but i can't do it. I expecting output like this

```
<ce:refers type="book" num="ref0015">DHO</ce:refers>
<ce:refers type="journal" num="ref0005">RTO</ce:refers>
<ce:refers type="book" num="ref0025">DHO</ce:refers>
<ce:refers type="journal" num="ref0030">RHO</ce:refers>
<ce:refers type="book" num="ref0035">DHO</ce:refers>
<ce:refers type="book" num="ref0010">EHO</ce:refers>
```

Comment: You could try to use `XML::Smart`. [Here](http://search.cpan.org/~tmharish/XML-Smart-1.79/lib/XML/Smart/Tutorial.pod) you have a tutorial. Then try to solve by yourself, if you can't, return on SO, post what you've tried and then wait for an help.

Answer (score 0):

Using [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML):

```
open data.xml ;
my $s     := sort :k @num //ce:refers/@num ;
my $last   = { $s->[-1] } ;
my $maxnum = xsh:match($last, '(\d+)') ;
for //ce:refers[not(count(@num))] {
    $maxnum += 5 ;
    set @num xsh:sprintf('ref%04d', $maxnum) ;
}
save :b ;
```

Note that the output is slightly different to the sample one (`ref0005` is missing in your sample).

Comment: It is possible to do using regex?

Comment: @user3415386: That's what `xsh:match` does.